# How can a `console_scripts` access file from `package_data`

Tags: python, python-2.7, setuptools, setup.py

When create a `console_scripts` as an `entry_points`, how do you access a data file (`package_data`) within the package?

```
setup(
    # other stuff
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'runme = mypackage.a_py_file:a_function_within_the_py_file',
        ]
    }
)
```

Directory structure:

```
├── mypackage
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── a_py_file.py
├── requirements.txt
├── setup.py
└── data 
    ├── a.data
    └── b.data
```

Python file to handle `console_scripts`:

```
# a_py_file.py
def a_function_within_the_py_file:
    # HOW TO READ a.data FILE HERE
```

Comment: Why not go with the somewhat standardized `python setup.py test` procedure?

Comment: @cel, the tests are not unit test. It's a few selenium test and my user doesn't have technical knowledge. I want to make it simpler for them. This way they just install a package and run it without knowing what it is. Just like many python tools out there that support command line invocations.

Comment: how do you package your app ? seems you create `tests` package in your pythonpath, if you want to install your tests it's better to move into `mypackage`, you reduce conflicts and will be easier to find them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is what I did and it worked:

```
import os
import pkg_resources

os.chdir(pkg_resources.get_distribution('mypackage').location)
# running as if the script is invoked from project's root
```

Answer (score 1):

How about changing `cwd`?

```
import os
os.chdir(__file__)
```

`conftest.py` sounds like a good place to do this. Or the file which is attached to your `test` command.